# Issue getting floor information using CLLocation and Google Map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-location, indoor-positioning-system

I'm using the CLLocation for getting the current floor of a mall.

```
private var currentLocation = CLLocation() {
    didSet {
        locationLabel.text = "Longitude = \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude) \nLatitude = \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
        if let level = currentLocation.floor?.level {
            floorLabel.text = "Floor = \(level)"
        } else {
            floorLabel.text = "No floor detected"
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let currentLocation = locations.first {
        self.currentLocation = currentLocation
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("locationManager didFailWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this code, its working fine until I load the google map. Here is the code.

```
@IBAction func mapInitClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: mapContainerView.bounds)
    mapView.autoresizesSubviews = true
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
    mapView.settings.compassButton = true
    mapView.settings.indoorPicker = false
    mapView.isIndoorEnabled = false
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.isBuildingsEnabled = false

    //mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    //floorLevel = mapView.indoorDisplay.activeLevel?.shortName
    if currentLocation.coordinate.latitude == 0.0
    {
        let newCamera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 40.7139018, longitude: -74.0156599, zoom: 19.5)
        mapView.camera = newCamera
    }
    else
    {
        let newCamera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 1.0)
        mapView.camera = newCamera
    }
    mapContainerView.addSubview(mapView)
}
```

As soon as I load the Google Map, I started getting the floor from the CLLocation as Nil. And following line of code is start to execute.

```
floorLabel.text = "No floor detected"
```

Does anyone know whats going wrong with it?

Comment: Not a single comment/answer on this community? Very strange.

Comment: Where do you call the API to update the location?

Comment: @vadian, the location will automatically update as soon as a user moves with the device.

Comment: Then it seems that the location manager doesn't detect floors.

Comment: No, it detects the floor until I load the Google Map. As soon as the map is load and show on screen, the floor detection is stopped working.

Comment: Help me please. I'm badly stuck here. I've also contact with the Google Map Support Team and they are looking into the issue from last 2 weeks which is very strange. Help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#indoor_maps) you should first of all turn `Indoor Maps` on:

```
mapView.isIndoorEnabled = true
```

Also the [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#adding_floor_plans):

> Floor plans are available in [select locations](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1685827). If floor plan data is not available for a building that you would like to highlight in your application, you can: 1) Add floor plans to Google Maps directly. This will make your plans are available to all users of Google Maps.
>   2) Display a floor plan as a Ground Overlay. This will enable only users of your application to view your floor plans.

Also consider that

> By default, no location data is shown on the map. You may enable the blue "My Location" dot and compass direction by setting myLocationEnabled on GMSMapView

```
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

More [details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#my_location) on that.